# Some selections I don't know how to write

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, so please forgive me if I ask stupid questions.

I have three tables, one with countries, one with cities (connected to countries, with populations...) and one with languages (also connected to countries).

I'd like to ask MySQL about the following informations:

1. the names of the countries for which all the cities have more than 100000 citizen,
2. the names of the countries for which at least one city is in the cities table,
3. the names of the countries where english is spoken, but not spanish,

and so on. I start to understand junctures, a little bit of grouping, but that's about all.

Comment: What is the structure of your tables?

Comment: @user36296 : thank you for your answer... It could help, but for now, it seems to be masked by my theme choice. I don't know how to send you a private message, sorry, I read yours in one question about SQL I posted a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First query

```sql
SELECT name FROM country WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT big_city.country_id FROM 
                  (SELECT country_id, COUNT(*) as n FROM city WHERE population > 100000 GROUP BY country_id) as big_city,
                  (SELECT country_id, COUNT(*) as n FROM city GROUP BY country_id)  
    as all_city WHERE big_city.country_id = all_city.country_id AND big_city.n = all_city.n)
```

What I'm doing here in the subqueries is making a list of countries with all registered towns having a population greater than 100'000 people.

#### Second query

```sql
SELECT country.name FROM country WHERE country.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT country_id FROM city);
```

Doing so you will get all the country IDs in the `city` table, so you can use this as a condition

#### Third query

```sql
SELECT country.name FROM country WHERE country.id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT country_id FROM language WHERE language = "en")
    AND NOT country.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT country_id FROM language WHERE language = "es")
```

Same as before, you fetch all the countries in which English or Spanish is spoken and you filter accordingly

Comment: This has been tested in SQLite, should work with MySQL too

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll work on your code to learn from it.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy SQLing!

Answer (score 1):

Provide more details like tables and database version:
If you consider the following script in SQLServer 2017:

```
create table countries
(
    [id] int not null identity,
    [name] varchar(100) not null,

    constraint pk_countries primary key ([id])
)
insert into countries ([name]) values ('Country 1'), ('Country 2'), ('Country 3')

create table cities
(
    [id] int not null identity,
    [idCountry] int not null,
    [name] varchar(100) not null,
    [population] int not null,

    constraint pk_cities primary key ([id]),
    constraint fk_cities_countries foreign key ([idCountry]) references countries ([id])
)
insert into cities ([idCountry], [name], [population]) values 
    (1, 'City 11', 1500000), (1, 'City 22', 2000000),
    (2, 'City 21', 2000000), (2, 'City 22', 100)

create table languages
(
    [id] int not null identity,
    [idCity] int not null,
    [name] varchar(100) not null,

    constraint pk_languages primary key ([id]),
    constraint fk_languages_cities foreign key ([idCity]) references cities ([id])
)
insert into languages ([idCity], [name]) values (1, 'Lang 1'), (1, 'Lang 2'), (1, 'Lang 3')


-- the names of the countries for which all the cities have more than 100000 citizen
select 
  distinct (a.name)
from
  countries a
where
  not exists (select * from cities where idCountry = a.id and population < 1000000) and
  exists (select * from cities where idCountry = a.id)

go

-- the names of the countries for which at least one city is in the cities table,
select 
  distinct (a.name)
from
  countries a
where
  exists (select * from cities where idCountry = a.id)
```

Results (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/326e0/1):

```
Country1

Country 1
Country 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I learn with MySQL (MariaDB, in fact), but I think this is not too different :-)